# how do you create an editable combobox addin for ArciGIS using Eclipse

Tags: arcgis-10.0, java, add-in, eclipse

Arc have a walkthrough to take you through this.  Looks like I'm still crawling.  The walkthrough can be found here:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#//0001000002sr000000

Everything in the walkthrough works fine but if I make the box editable each keystroke is entered as a new option.  So "blah" typed into the combo box would create the following options within the combobox:

b
bl
bla
blah

I'm sure onEnter() method needs to tie in with the onEditChange() method.  But trying to incorporate this just adds blank options.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Answered here in stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983778/how-do-you-make-the-arcgis-combobox-editable